# Is there a lighted buckling-spring (or similiar feel) keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, backlight

I got a buckling-spring (IBM Model-M style) keyboard from [Unicomp](http://pckeyboards.stores.yahoo.net/keyboards.html) a while back and have found it to be a pretty solid keyboard.  I recently put my MacbookPro on a laptop stand, so I've been using the external keyboard more.  Now, the laptop has lighted keys, though I rarely use them because it's right in front of the backlit screen.  Is there any way I can have the best both worlds - a solid keyboard that I can see without turning on another light in the room?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Deck Keyboards](http://deckkeyboards.com/) makes backlit keyboards that have tactile feedback, but they aren't the super-duper clicky keys of the Model-Ms.

It looks like the [force specs for the Cherry keys they use](http://www.cherrycorp.com/english/switches/key/mx.htm) are pretty close to those specified in the [Model-M patent](http://www.google.com/patents?id=WpAwAAAAEBAJ&zoom=4&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q=&f=false), even without the noise.

I might have to pick one of these up myself.